# Ubuntu resets settings every time it restarts

Tags: boot, usb

I know why this happens and its because it runs off a usb stick since I was trying to install it onto a hard drive without a OS. How can I fix this. Can you fix this by booting it up then downloading it and installing it? Will that automatically place it on the Hard Drive? Also just how can I fix this. So will just opening by using the flash drive as boot then installing it on the browser in ubuntu then installing it through the website fix this? Please help!

Comment: If you're running from an Ubuntu USB stick and want to permanently install it to the hard drive - just launch the installer (there's an "Install ubuntu" Icon in the dash).

Comment: thnx apreciate it